# TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby

I have code:

```
class Scene
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end
  attr_reader :number
end

scenes = [Scene.new("one"), Scene.new("one"), Scene.new("two"), Scene.new("one")]

groups = scenes.inject({}) do |new_hash, scene|
   new_hash[scene.number] = [] if new_hash[scene.number].nil?
   new_hash[scene.number] << scene
end
```

When I'm lauching it I get error:

```
freq.rb:11:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
       from freq.rb:11:in `block in <main>'
       from freq.rb:10:in `each'
       from freq.rb:10:in `inject'
       from freq.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

If I change scenes to:

```
scenes = [Scene.new(1), Scene.new(1), Scene.new(2), Scene.new(1)]
```

the problem dissapear.

Why I get error message in the first case? Why Ruby decide to convert scene.number from String to Integer?

And one additional question about the 'inject' method.  When Ruby initialize the 'new_hash' variable and how can Ruby know the type of this variable?

Comment: Btw: you can do what you want more easily by using `groups = scenes.group_by(&:number)` instead of inject.

Comment: The new_hash variable is initialized with the injected value (keep in mind: it's a folding operation which has a start value in the accumulator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Z.E.D.'s right. See [Jay Fields' Thoughts: Ruby: inject](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html) for a good explanation of `inject` by example.

As presented, your block returns an array. So the `new_hash` in `|new_hash, scene|` ends up being that array. When Ruby tries to find the array index 'one', it throws the error because 'one' is a String, not an Integer.

All you need to do is return `new_hash` as Z.E.D. showed, and you'll get something like this:

```
{
  "two" => [
    #<Scene:0x101836470 @number="two">
  ],
  "one" => [
    #<Scene:0x101836510 @number="one">,
    #<Scene:0x1018364c0 @number="one">,
    #<Scene:0x101836420 @number="one">
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
groups = scenes.inject({}) do |new_hash, scene|
   new_hash[scene.number] = [] if new_hash[scene.number].nil?
   new_hash[scene.number] << scene
   new_hash
end
```

Ruby takes the empty hash passed into inject() and sets new_hash to that. When the block ends the return value gets used to initialize new_hash the next time through, i.e., new_hash keeps accumulating the result of the block.

In your original code you were not returning the hash but an array (new_hash[scene.number] is an array) and the next loop through Ruby complained because new_hash[scene.number] was trying to do a lookup into the array with a string value, hence the error you got.

Comment: @shingara: No, it doesn't fail. His code runs without error and returns the expected result.

Comment: Thank you sepp2k. I agree, "why was it downvoted?" It ran right, fixed the bug in his code and explained the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Enumerable.html#M001150) which is probably exactly what you try to accomblish?

```
groups = scenes.group_by(&:number)
# => {"two"=>[#<Scene:0xb728ade0 @number="two">],
#     "one"=>
#       [#<Scene:0xb728ae30 @number="one">,
#        #<Scene:0xb728ae08 @number="one">,
#        #<Scene:0xb728ada4 @number="one">]}
```

`inject` is a folding operation and not exactly what you want. At least it's cumbersome to use in this way. `merge` with a block would probably be appropriate if you want to apply some algorithm during merging or grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to explain 'how can Ruby know the type of this variable' and why it tries to 'convert String into Integer' you might want to revise: [Ruby variables and dynamic typing](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Ruby_Variables#Ruby_and_Variable_Dynamic_Typing).

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer is accepted for this question, but I can't help but post my answer.

```
groups = scenes.inject({}) { |nh, s| nh.tap {|h| (h[s.number] ||= []) << s } }
```